# Displaying Elements in Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data stored in multiple arrays. I want to be able to display the elements in each array on the page using innerHTML. The problem is is that each time through the for-loop the next element in the array overwrites the previous element. How do I display all elements at once without anything being overwritten? Here is my set up:

```
 for(var item in list){
     document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Results: " + item;
  }
```

So that might display the contents of the first array and then i'd create another loop to display contents of second array, etc. Is there a better way to display the contents of multiple arrays such that nothing overwrites previous content?

Comment: You could do `.innerHTML += 'more results'`

Comment: Also, best not to use `for...in` loops for arrays. Reserve that loop for objects.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code to

```
for(var item in list){
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Results: ";
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML+ item;
    // Or same way to write it
    // document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += item;
}
```

Comment: This prints the items but it also repeats "Results" in between printed elements.